# Flutter ModalBottomSheet state (Radio buttons)

Tags: flutter, radio-button, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I can't update my state inside modalBottomSheet when i am using radio buttons. When I am changing the radio buttons i am retrieving data from server and i want to update the state.

here is my code

Here i am calling the modalBottomSheet:

```
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
         showModalBottomSheet(
         context: context,
         builder:
         buildBottomSheet);
         },
         child: ListTile(
         leading: Icon(
         Icons.shopping_basket),
         title:
         Text("choose bag type "),
         ),
   ),
```

And here is my modalbottomSheet with container which contains radio buttons.

```
  Widget buildBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter state) {
      return Container(
        color: Color(0xff757575),
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(25), topRight: Radius.circular(25))),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              RadioListTile(
                groupValue: _con.cart.bagType,
                title: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            S.of(context).plastic_bag +
                                " (" +
                                _con.cart.plasticBagCount.toString() +
                                " X " +
                                _con.cart.plasticBagUnitPrice.toString() +
                                ")",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 1,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Image.asset("assets/img/business.png",
                          height: 25, color: Colors.grey),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                value: 1,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  state(() {
                    selectedBagType = val;
                  });

                  _con.cart.bagType = val;
                  print("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" + val.toString());
                  _con.listenForBagTypeChange();
                },
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                groupValue: _con.cart.bagType,
                title: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Text(
                        S.of(context).reusable_bag +
                            " (" +
                            _con.cart.reusableBagCount.toString() +
                            " X " +
                            _con.cart.reusableBagUnitPrice.toString() +
                            ")",
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_basket,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 30.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                value: 2,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  state(() {
                    selectedBagType = val;
                  });

                  _con.cart.bagType = val;
                  print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" + val.toString());
                  _con.listenForBagTypeChange();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

please anyone can help ?

Comment: state(() { selectedBagType = val; }); Here, use setState().

Comment: I have tried setState it is not working at all

Comment: Is there any error you are getting? Can you post your complete dart file?

Comment: no i am not getting any error just the state is not updating inside modalBottomSheet. sorry but file is huge and stackoverflow is not excepting it